# How do I copy subdirectories of a working copy in svn 1.7 while keeping the metadata?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

svn 1.7 [improves the working copy metadata format](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng) so there are no .svn directories in every directory of a working copy but one central store per working copy.

Now I want to copy *sudirectories* of a wcorking copy to another place (not check them out in the new place) where there is no working copy and use them there with svn (and all this on Windows with TortoiseSVN or the commandline). This was easy till 1.6 (just copy the directories), but now obviously the copies don't have any metadata attached anymore.

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not supported yet. See http://www.mail-archive.com/users@subversion.apache.org/msg09857.html

You'll have to do a fresh checkout, or to copy the subtree and do a switch on this subtree.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround probably still has the network transfer overhead but keeps your local non-commited changes:

1. Write down the revision of your working copy (update if desired)
2. Copy/move the subdirectory to the desired location
3. Do a checkout with the URL of the subdirectory and the revision noted *over* your detached directory (you may need --force)